# Can't displayed the UI in Google document

Tags: google-apps-script

I put theese script in to the Google document but it does nothing. I can't see the UI in the document.

```
function demoUI() {
var myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('An improved GUI');

var mygrid = myapp.createGrid(3, 2);
mygrid.setWidget(0, 0, myapp.createLabel('Name:'));
mygrid.setWidget(0, 1, myapp.createTextBox());
mygrid.setWidget(1, 0, myapp.createLabel('Age:'));
mygrid.setWidget(1, 1, myapp.createTextBox());
mygrid.setWidget(2, 0, myapp.createLabel('City'));
mygrid.setWidget(2, 1, myapp.createTextBox());

var mybutton = myapp.createButton('Press me');
var mypanel = myapp.createVerticalPanel();
mypanel.add(mygrid);
mypanel.add(mybutton);
myapp.add(mypanel);
return myapp;
}​
```

Comment: How do you call the `demoUI` function?

Answer (score 0):

Are you operating in a Google Doc container? In which case the approach to displaying ui's is different, you either need to put them in a sidebar or a dialog, please have a look here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs#custom_menus_and_user_interfaces

Answer (score 0):

You should replace:

```
return myapp;
```

by:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.show(myapp);
```

At last, you should have:

```
function demoUI() {
  var myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('An improved GUI');

  var mygrid = myapp.createGrid(3, 2);
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 0, myapp.createLabel('Name:'));
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 1, myapp.createTextBox());
  mygrid.setWidget(1, 0, myapp.createLabel('Age:'));
  mygrid.setWidget(1, 1, myapp.createTextBox());
  mygrid.setWidget(2, 0, myapp.createLabel('City'));
  mygrid.setWidget(2, 1, myapp.createTextBox());

  var mybutton = myapp.createButton('Press me');
  var mypanel = myapp.createVerticalPanel();
  mypanel.add(mygrid);
  mypanel.add(mybutton);
  myapp.add(mypanel);


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.show(myapp);
 }
```